# Converting memory hex string to an int

Tags: c#, string, memory, hex, port

I'm working on serial port communication and I have some info in a bat file which is encoded. I need to extract the file size which I translated to hex but it's flipped(something to do with memory) and i need to get the correct size.

[Here is the hex I have in my bat file(converted to decimal it's : 1178534144)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keUq0.png)
So I'm having alot of problems converting it...

[and here is the hex number I need to get(int decimal it's 81734)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqpnD.png)

**EDIT

Here's 64 bytes out of the bat file which I converted to hex cause in ASCII it's unreadable. [Focus on the part marked with red(whole hex) and part in blue(it's the hex number I need to convert from 46 3f 01 00 to 0013f46](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2f6E.png)

Comment: I can't seem to find a good way to convert it...

Comment: You should probably provide some background, what does "which I translated to hex" involve? Usually you would only ever deal with hexadecimal strings when you *deliberately produce one for display purposes*.  A serial device is not going to return a string of hexadecimal characters ...

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Convert.ToInt32-Methode: (String, Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614(v=vs.110).aspx) with the base as parameter

> The base of the number in value, which must be 2, 8, 10, or 16.

So the code would be (16 for base 16 aka hex)

```
int result = Convert.ToInt32("463F0100", 16); // 1178534144
```

Answer (score 0):

The decimal number 1178534144 is 0x463F0100. To get decimal 81734 you need to rotate 4 bytes to get 0x00013F46.
Under Windows you can include winsock.h and use function ntohl.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-ntohl

Comment: Yes that's what I'm asking here.. I can't seem to find a way to automatically rotate the bytes(only by hardcoding). It needs to be automatic in case the bat file has another number and it needs to convert it.

Comment: For this you should provide some background on the protocol of sender. Usually strings are transferred as is but the rotation only required for numbers.